# how to let the user select a single value from the list of values echoed below the input field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to select a single value from the list of values that are retrieved from database. the problem is that when user types suppose f, and there are 2 or more than 2 values in database, then a 
 tag is visible on the filed. How should I remove that br that is displayed between the values. Please help.

Controller page->admin_c.php

```
  public function get_values_c()
      {
        $e_name = $_REQUEST['ename'];

        $res = $this->admin_m->get_ename_m($e_name);

        if(sizeof($res)>0)
            echo implode("</br>",$res);

      }
```

Model page->admin_m.php

```
          public function get_ename_m($e_name)
      {
        $ename_value = [];

        if($e_name!="")
        {
            $sql = "select distinct ename from event where ename like '$e_name%'";
            $res = $this->db->query($sql);
            foreach($res->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $ename_value[] = $row['ename'];
            }
            return $ename_value;                    
        }
      }
```

View page->edit_event.php

```
<div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom:10px;">

                  <label class="control-label" style="margin-left:-64px;">Event Name</label>

                  <div class="controls" style="margin-left:28%">

                    <input type="text" class="span11" placeholder="Event name" name="ename" id="ename" style="width:95% !important;margin-left: -28px !important;">


                    <span class="span11" id="show_ename"  style="display:none;width:95% !important;margin-left: -28px !important;background-color:white;font-size:15px;"></span>

                  </div>

                </div>
```

Ajax code in View page:

```
$('#ename').keyup(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo site_url()."/admin_c/get_values_c";?>',
                method:'post',
                data:{'ename':$(this).val()},
                success: function(res,res1){
                    $('#show_ename').show();
                    $('#show_ename').html('');
                    $('#show_ename').html(res);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#show_ename').click(function(){
            var ename_value = $(this).html();
            $('#ename').val(ename_value);
            $(this).html('');
            $(this).hide();
        });
```

The working of this code is attached for reference:[image: Working]

Comment: Invalid HTML `</br>` Valid HTML `<br />` or `<br>`

Comment: still same output..

Comment: Check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6REieQ1SyA&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGJA_SN2O9t5DSlz7PTwAru) how to make it in plain PHP outside of the box. Then convert it to CI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are tying to copy **all** the output that is echoed from server to the input box. 
Since the output from `http://your-siteurl/admin_c/get_values_c` contains `<br>` tag the input box will just try to print. html input box does not render html elements . it just print html tags if there is any.

so to do what you want, i suggest these edits .

1st one is on **Controller page->admin_c.php**  , before implode function, use :

```
foreach ($res as $key => &$value){
 $value = "<div class='innerelement'>".$value."</div>";
}
echo implode("<br>",$res);
```

2nd replace your jquery click fuction by this code:

```
$("#show_ename").on("click",".innerelement", function(){
  var ename_value = $(this).html();
  $('#ename').val(ename_value);
  $(this).html('');
  $('#show_ename .innerelement').hide();
});
```

Note that in `url:'<?php echo site_url()."/admin_c/get_values_c";?>'` there is an extra "/"  after siteurl() function call replace like this :
`url:'<?php echo site_url()."admin_c/get_values_c";?>'`
or use
`url:'<?php echo site_url('admin_c/get_values_c');?>`